# Conditional compilation in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I have an Elixir module that contains a demo that I use in development and for integration testing with other systems. I do not want that module to be compiled for the prod environment. Is there some cute trick with mix/config I can use to make sure this module is unavailable in certain contexts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way Phoenix solves this problem is by specifying different value for `elixirc_paths` in `mix.exs` for different environments. Here's how you can achieve that:

```
def project do
  [
    ..,
    elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
    ..,
  ]
end

defp elixirc_paths(:prod), do: ["lib"]
defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib", "not-prod"]
```

Now put your `.ex` files that you want to not be present in `:prod` inside `/not-prod/` (You might want to use a better name for this...).